# gzip working but YSlow indicates it's not

Tags: .htaccess, compression, firebug, gzip, yslow

I'm getting used to **Firebug** and **YSlow** in particular. One of the things I'm looking at is the gzip compression. YSlow still gives my site an "F" and indicates that my CSS and JavaScript files are not being compressed.

However, if I run an external gzip test against my site (such as `http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php`) it tells me that gzip is working and gives me my savings, although I think this may just be the HTML.

This is the relevant section of my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on       Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk  Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file      \.css$
    mod_gzip_item_include file      \.(html?|txt|js|php|pl|jpg|png|gif)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler   ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
```

Why does YSlow not agree with the external gzip test?

Comment: Apologies, the line breaks in my code sample seem to have been lost. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears you're asking for `gzip` on `jpg` `png` and `gif`, there's no point, `zlib` can't improve upon these. (No idea on the actual _point_ of your question. Sorry. :)

Comment: Hi sarnold, Any ideas on if gzip is not working for css/javascript on my site, or if YSlow is not recognizing the compression. Basically I'm trying to gzip the files on my website using the code above, however YSlow is saying that my css and javascript files are not being compressed when I believe they should. I believe css, html, txt, js, php, pl, jpg, png and gif files should be compressed but I dont think this is happening. Any ideas

Comment: @scm8jet, what do the headers look like when you use a tool like `HEAD` to retrieve the headers, or look at the headers with Wireshark when using a browser?

Comment: @sarnold, thanks for coming back to me. I'm not familiar with HEAD, do you have a URL to point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: @scm8jet, `HEAD` is included in the `libwww-perl` package, perhaps your distribution has it easily available; if not, you can find more details on [cpan](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/). You can also use `wget --server-response http://example.com/` or `curl -I http://example.com/` if `HEAD` isn't easily installable. (I like `HEAD` because it is easier to remember than either `wget` or `curl` command line options. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod_gzip` is an obsolete part of Apache 1.*x*, having been replaced by `mod_deflate` in Apache 2.

This `mod_deflate` configuration makes YSlow happy here:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/html text/plain text/xml
    DeflateCompressionLevel 9
</IfModule>
```

The only reason there are two `AddOutputFilterByType` lines is to avoid horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Not measuring behind a proxy?  My work proxy screws with my yslow results...!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the next code to your .htaccess

```
# BEGIN GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
# END GZIP
```

Seems it makes both GTmetrix & Yslow happy

Don't forget to add

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

at the beginning of your header file if your are using **PHP**