# Enable gzip compression

Tags: performance, apache, compression, gzip

My website running on Apache 2, modGzip and deflate enabled and working!

I add the following code on my htaccces file but if I check my page on gzip compression test. no Compression..

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

I searched alot and tried other mod or deflate codes but none of them work..what do I do to enable gzip compression?

Thanx alot!

Answer (score 1):

**For Apache**

You will need to add the following lines to your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
<IfModule>
```

After you've saved your .htaccess file, test your site to make sure it has been properly compressed.

**Reference:** http://websitespeedoptimizations.com/OptimizeGzipCompressionPost.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml text/x-js text/js 
</IfModule>
```

That should do it. You'll want to clear you browser cache, refresh and retest in Google PageSpeed or YSlow to ensure you've gained some speed.

(and you may need to add some of your own mime-types to the mix)

EDIT: Here are the Apache docs on compression if that helps to customize/get this working. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

EDIT 2: I would also check this answer out [gzip working but YSlow indicates it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603739/gzip-working-but-yslow-indicates-its-not?rq=1)

Comment: Gzip is not enabled. I checked on checkgzipcompression.com and google page speed test.

Comment: Do you have a link you can share?

Comment: I read that page and I added AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml to my htaccess file. Man!! I checked on gziptest.com it says gzip enabled! all the other gzip test webpages say no it is not! and google says still enable gzip.. I guess It is not working..

Comment: When I use PageSpeed in Firefox, sometimes it takes clearing cache, quitting firefox, reopening and refreshing more than once before I get positive feedback. I would give that a try.

Comment: I added one hour ago and nothing changes.. why can it be so complicated:S thanx mate anyway!

Answer (score 0):

**What is compression?**

Compression allows your webserver to provide smaller file sizes that load faster for your website users.

Compression of your HTML and CSS files with gzip typically saves around fifty to seventy percent of the file size. This means that it takes less time to load your pages, and less bandwidth is used overall.

How to enable Gzip compression
Compression is enabled via webserver configuration
Different web servers have different instructions (explained below)
Here are the most common ways to enable compression including .htaccess, Apache, Nginx, and Litespeed webservers.

**Enable compression via .htaccess**

The code below should be added to your .htaccess file…

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

**Enable compression on Apache webservers**

if they are not working there is another way that may work for you. If the above code did not seem to work, remove it from your .htaccess file and try this one instead…

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

**I hope it's working Fine**